# tfrupee prints bold symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tfrupee}

\begin{document}

This is a \rupee{} symbol

This is a \rupee symbol

\textbf{This is a \rupee{} symbol}

\textbf{This is a \rupee symbol}

\end{document}
```

I have tried compiling using pdflatex, xetex and luatex. But the Rupee symbol always prints in bold! How do I get Rupee symbol in 'normal' font?

Comment: I think this is 'just how it is': the font selected is 'medium weight' not 'bold weight', so there is not much to do really.

Comment: This package just contains one symbol. Therefore, you will not get a "normal" font version. You should post an image of that symbol and ask for recreation of it. Or you contact Palle Jørgensen or the maintainer of this font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a font that only provides the official Indian rupee symbol, a font family is needed with adopted versions for the different font variants.

Example for LuaTeX (similar is XeTeX except that SourceCodePro and SourceSansPro probably need a more complicate `\fontspec` setting to get
them working):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\tracinglostchars=2 % get a message, if glyphs are missing

\newcommand*{\rupee}{%
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{FreeSans}% add your font here
    ^^^^20b9%
  \endgroup
}

% test fonts

\newcommand*{\TestString}{This is a ^^^^20b9 symbol.}
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \subsubsection*{#1}
  \begingroup
    \fontspec{#1}%
    \TestString\\
    \textbf{\TestString}\\
    \textit{\TestString}\\
    \textbf{\itshape\TestString}\par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
  \test{ClearSans}
  \test{DejaVuSans}
  \test{DejaVuSerif}
  \test{FreeMono}
  \test{FreeSans}
  \test{FreeSerif}
  \test{SourceCodePro}
  \test{SourceSansPro}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

The package `tfrupee` provides just one symbol which is already called from a medium weight font. Therefore, you will have to accept that symbol as it is.

As you are able to use Xe- or LuaLatex, you may just use the unicode of this symbol together with some font, that fits your needs. If you need help in writing a macro with just one symbol in a certain font, let me know!

The symbol you want to have is mapped under the unicode [U+20B9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm). I also added the alternative version [U+20A8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a8/index.htm). If you want to see, which fonts on your system provide that symbol, you may want to click [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%82%B9%20-%20INDIAN%20RUPEE%20SIGN%20%28U%2B20B9%29). An SVG-version for further treatment can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/indian_rupee_sign.svg).

```
% arara: lualatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{Quivira.otf}\symbol{"20B9}\symbol{"20A8}   

    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}\symbol{"20B9}%\symbol{"20A8} % not existent

    \setmainfont{Symbola.ttf}\symbol{"20B9}\symbol{"20A8}

    \setmainfont{EB Garamond}\symbol{"20B9}\symbol{"20A8}

    \setmainfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}\symbol{"20B9}\symbol{"20A8}
\end{document}
```

[image]